# Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo

Tags: php, dns, centos7, centos-web-panel

I own a DEDICATED server and installed CENTOS 7 with installed WEB Panel and PHP Version 8.1.13

Everything was working fine from last 12 days until I tried to created a simple web crawl script to run .

```
<?php
include ("simple_html_dom.php");
$html =file_get_html("https://www.bbc.com");
echo $html;

foreach($html-> find("div li") as $h)
{
    echo $h-> text();
}

?>
```

It gave me an error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for www.bbc.com failed: Name or service not known in home/myserver/public_html/news/simple_html_dom.php on line 82

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.bbc.com): Failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for www.bbc.com failed: Name or service not known in /home/myserver/public_html/news/simple_html_dom.php on line 82

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on bool in home/myserver/public_html/news/tim.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/myserver/public_html/news/tim.php on line 6
```

I also looked for the logs on the server . It shows for many other domains too

[image]

To find the solution , I looked upon many videos tutorial and read several posts. What I know that this problem is due to mis configuration on DNS server side. I looked upon solution but none of the them worked me . I would be very thankful if someone please guide me to fix this DNS error.

I have already checked the basic configuration on server side and it looked very fine to me. Moreover I am very cautious to break the existing configuration.

Comment: You might be better asking on Server Fault if you want help with things like DNS config. You'll need to provide some details about the existing configuration and the O/S etc before you will get meaningful help, I expect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your IP address was blocked or temporary restricted. Crawl process way complex than just getting data by file_get_contents. You should take care about headers, cookies, sessions maybe. Just to be like a normal user.

Also, you can use public API. Usually big sites like BBC have it to avoid big load to HTTP channel. For example: https://apitracker.io/a/bbc-news

Also, you can subscribe to RSS feed of BBC and check updates by it. It will be way easier to organise downloading content. For example: https://gist.github.com/mburst/5230448

Comment: Thanks. BBC was just an example. It doesn't for any of the website . The problem is that the server is not able to resolve the URL. The php crawl is temporary code for the test.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: ah, ok, maybe you have a DNS issue. You can check it by nslookup command. And just to avoid php layer and be sure it's DNS issue. You can try to use curl cli tool to check website availability.